# Entity framework: InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I using Entity Framework to execute Stored Procedures (Azure SQL Server) in my data-base.

My C# code looks like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    numberOfEffectedRows = context.MySPName(this.Id);
```

In most cases (99.9%) of the executions, this works fine. But, sometimes it's failed with this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Rollback()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.Dispose(DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass4b.<ExecuteFunction>b__49()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at ***.MyDataContext.MySPName(Nullable`1 Id) in ***
   at ***.DoSomething() in ***
```

When this happening:

1. I don't know why it's happens. It's seems to me like randomized.
2. I don't know whether my "MySPName" was executed or not.

Someone known why this happens and how I can know if my Stored Procedure is executed or not?

Comment: Is the code snippet you pasted the one throwing exception?

Comment: Yes. According to the StackTrace the code line 'context.MySPName(this.Id);' is the source of the exception.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Make sure you enumerate the query before you leave the using statement, EF uses deferred execution

Comment: numberOfEffectedRows is int. Copied by Value.

Answer (score 2):

Linq queries are evaluated lazily. The query will run the first time you access the numberOfEffectedRows. Since you use "using" around the creation of the data context, it gets disposed once goes off scope. If you access numberOfEffectedRows outside the scope of using, then this would happen since query can't run without valid data context.

Comment: No LINQ in my code. Copy the value to "numberOfEffectedRows" is done "by value".

Comment: I still think that it has something to do with your using statement around data context creation because of all these dispose method calls in the stack trace and then it tries to validate the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is closed is due to timeout, so suggest you to check your `Connect Timeout` in your connection string

```
 connectionString="Data Source=..;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=..;User ID=..;Password=..;Connect Timeout=.."
```

For diagnostic i suggest you to run `SQL Server Profiler`

Comment: How do you know it is due to timeout?

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework context is not thread safe, it is possible that the data context is closed during the execution for some strange reason.

one way to handle this kind of surprise is to have one context for each request.

this is the easiest solution, so you will "hopefully" never encounter this exception again.

check here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx

what you can do is

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, MyDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

and then you inject the DataContext anywhere you need to access it.

doing so the context will automatically close when the container is disposed

Comment: “ to have one context for each request. ” Is it what code in the question goes?  : using (var context = new MyDataContext())